# How to copy one table column to another respecting row names?

Tags: matlab

In the following toy example, tables `t1` and `t2` have shapes (3 x 0) and (3 x 1), respectively.  Furthermore, both tables have the same row names.

```
>> t1 = table('RowNames', {'a', 'b', 'c'});
>> t2 = table([3 ; 2 ; 1], ...
              'RowNames', {'c', 'a', 'b'}, 'VariableNames', {'x'});
```

Then a copy of `t2`'s single column is added to `t1` as a new column, with the same variable name.

```
>> t1.('x') = t2.('x');
```

The resulting table `t1`, however, differs from `t2` in the association between row names and the values in the `x`-column:

```
>> t1({'a', 'b', 'c'}, :)
ans =
         x
         _
    a    3
    b    2
    c    1
>> t2({'a', 'b', 'c'}, :)
ans =
         x
         _
    a    2
    b    1
    c    3
```

What's the simplest way to assign `t2.('x')` to `t1.('x')` "respecting rownames"?  By this last condition I mean that the final `t1` should look just like `t2`; e.g.:

```
>> t1({'a', 'b', 'c'}, :)
ans =
         x
         _
    a    2
    b    1
    c    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index the table using row names so if you extract the list of rownames from `t1` you can use that as the ordering for `t2`:

```
order = t1.Properties.RowNames % cell array
intermediate = t2(order, :);
```

or just do it all in one go:

```
t2(t1.Properties.RowNames, :);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `t1` doesn't have the `x` column you can concatenate `t1` with column `x` of `t2`

```
>> t1=[t1, t2(:,'x')]
t1 = 
         x
         _
    a    2
    b    1
    c    3
```

It will automatically take care of matching rows.

Comment: So it does! Indeed `[t1 t2]` seems to work too. I had wondered what the advantages were of the `table` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the OP here.

I found a (potential) answer to my question: instead of

```
t1.('x') = t2.('x');
```

use

```
t1.('x') = t2{t1.Properties.RowNames, 'x'};
```

I say that this is a "potential" answer because with MATLAB I never know when something that works for a particular type, or under particular circumstances, will generalize.  E.g., at this point I don't know if the above will work if column `x` holds non-numeric values.

If someone knows of a better way, or can point to documentation in support of my lucky guess here, please post it.  I'll be glad to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Crossed in the post : ) The `Properties.RowNames` property is indeed the key.